# scala challenge - what am I missing?

Tags: scala

Working through the [99 scala problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) and confused by problem 23. To my eyes, the example is incongruent with the stated problem. Specifically the Symbol 'e in the resulting list isn't in among the input. Am I missing something?

Problem and example are as follows:

```
P23 (**) Extract a given number of randomly selected elements from a list.
    Example:

    scala> randomSelect(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'f, 'g, 'h))
    res0: List[Symbol] = List('e, 'd, 'a)

    Hint: Use the solution to problem P20
```

Comment: That's just a typo.  I looked at the solution and it would never add an extra letter.  You could contact the author via the feedback link on the page.

Comment: alright cool - I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks so!

Comment: @BenReich - i see the comment has a few upvotes - if you post the same as an answer I'll accept it so you get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a typo. I looked at the solution and it would never add an extra letter.

Furthermore, these Scala problems are an adaptation of these [Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/).  You can see the equivalent question there, and note the `e` in the example:

```
P23 (**) Extract a given number of randomly selected elements from a list.
    The selected items shall be put into a result list.

Example:
    ?- rnd_select([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],3,L).
    L = [e,d,a]
```

You could contact the author via the feedback link on the page, if you are so inclined.

Comment: Thanks for the link to 99 Prolog Problems, have not played it through yet.